# Set a font specifically for all numbers on the page

Tags: javascript, css, regex, numbers, font-family

For my webpage, I chose a font that works well for all the letters. However, for all numbers I'd like to use a different font.

Is there a way that I can set a CSS rule to target all the numbers on the page?

If I can't do it strictly with CSS, my first thought is to use regular expressions to surround all numbers with a span with a "numbers" class and apply a font for that class. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if this will be useful, but have a look at it. http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2012/jquery/targeting-a-specific-word-using-javascript-and-jquery/

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript as you've described, or you can create a custom font by replacing the number glyphs in your "letters" font with the number glyphs in your "numbers" font.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it in JavaScript relatively simply by traversing the document so that you wrap any sequence of digits in a `span` element with a `class` attribute and declare `font-family` for it in CSS.

It’s possible in principle in pure CSS, too, though only WebKit browsers currently support this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myArial;
  src: local("Courier New");
  unicode-range: U+30-39;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myArial;
  src: local("Arial");
  unicode-range: U+0-2f, U+40-10FFFF;
}
body { font-family: myArial; }
```

Finally, and most importantly, don’t do it. If you are dissatisfied with digits in a font, don’t use that font.

Comment: I checked out the [CSS3 Font spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#unicode-range-desc) on `unicode-range`...interesting.

Comment: This is good solution. Can you help me how can I use like that: 
  @font-face{
    font-family: myArial;
    src: local("Times New Roman", Times, serif);
    unicode-range: U+30-39;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding your numbers with a `<span class="number">` sounds like a good, semantically sound approach.

In fact, CSS3 doesn't offer an alternative, and I don't see anything forthcoming in [CSS4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-selectors4-20120823/). If you look at the [latest CSS3 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors), it doesn't specify any content selector, but the old [2001 candidate recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors) was the last version to provide the `:contains()` pseudoclass.

This would let you match an element that contained numbers:

```
/* Deprecated CSS3 */
p:contains(0), p:contains("1"), p:contains("2") {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Even if this were actually available, it matches the `p`, not the number, so the whole `p` would be styled...not what you wanted. The CSSWG is kicking around [these ideas](http://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting) for formatting numerical content...still not what you wanted.

To apply CSS to the numbers, there is no avoiding some additional markup.