# Set font-family just for numbers

Tags: html, css, fonts

In my project i set `font-family: 'Droid Arabic Naskh'`.
I have problem with numbers. Numbers will show in Arabic but i want numbers show in English. 
How can i set one special font just for numbers that show numbers in English ?

I tested this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Droid Arabic Naskh" !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    src: url("font-awesome/fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("font-awesome/fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("font-awesome/fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf") format("truetype") !important;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Droid Arabic Naskh" !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    src: url("font-awesome/fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("font-awesome/fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
    url("font-awesome/fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf") format("truetype") !important;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: arial;
    src: url("font-awesome/fonts/arial.ttf") format("truetype") !important;
    unicode-range: U+30-39;
}

body{font-family:'Droid Arabic Naskh', arial }
```

Comment: In which browser(s) did you test this?

Comment: @ElhamGdz please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611420/set-a-font-specifically-for-all-numbers-on-the-page

Comment: @Jukkak.Korpela: I test it in Firefox, chrome and IE and just in IE it is worked. How can i do it for Firefox and chrome ?

Comment: @ElhamGdz, the question has been closed as a duplicate. Maybe incorrectly, but there isn’t really enough information given in this question. What are the fonts you are using? (Where did you get them, and how did you you generate the font files?) And what is the *content*? Are you trying to style Arabic digit characters (٠, ‎١, ‎٢,…) as European digits (0, 1, 2…)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define both ranges:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: your_font;
    src: url("font-awesome/fonts/YOUR_FONT.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: your_font;
    src: url("font-awesome/fonts/arial.ttf");
    unicode-range: U+30-39;
}


body{font-family:'your_font' }
```

Comment: how is it different from what OP ha posted?

Comment: The font-family is the same now, but for some characters it takes one font, and for others, it takes the other one.

Comment: @User3576550 i exactly test this before you say but it doesn't work, i edite my code.

Comment: @ElhamGdz : i know the question may sound stupid....but are you running the page through localhost or directly in browser?

Comment: @NoobEditor: why you think this question may sound stupid?!!! I running in localhost.