# All numbers on webpage appear in superscript

Tags: css, numbers

I'm very weak in HTML / CSS / javascript but wanted to modify my website to be responsive to all devices. To this end I downloaded a responsive web design template ([output here](http://pixelsbyrick.com/demos/gumba.html); source downloadable [here](http://pixelsbyrick.com/downloads/gumba-template.html)) and tried to work my own site's content into it. Everything is fine except that all numbers on the page appear in superscript. This is true even on the original template so the issue is apparently due to the CSS style sheet used by the template.

None of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611420/set-a-font-specifically-for-all-numbers-on-the-page) for standardizing font for numbers appear to be implemented; nor can I find any implementation of superscript or top-alignment of text in the CSS sheet that would affect numbers specifically.

The CSS style sheet code is as follows, with an example showing what happens to numbers. Any assistance on identifying why the number is superscript is appreciated.

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

html, body {
  font-size: 100%;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

audio, canvas, video {
  display: inline-block;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

html, button, input, select, textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  outline: 0;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b, strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

blockquote {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

pre, code, kbd, samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  _font-family: 'courier new', monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

small {
  font-size: 75%;
}

sub, sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

nav ul, nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

button, input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button[disabled], input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration, input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Neat 1.7.0
 * http://neat.bourbon.io
 * Copyright 2012-2014 thoughtbot, inc.
 * MIT License */
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
  font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-color: #22272a;
  color: #ced9e0;
  font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 0.75em;
  font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
  color: #ced9e0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #9fb5c2;
  border-color: #9fb5c2;
}
a:active, a:focus {
  color: #9fb5c2;
  border-color: #9fb5c2;
  outline: none;
}

header {
  color: #fff;
}

hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

img,
picture {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

blockquote {
  border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
  color: #fdfdfe;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
}

cite {
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
}
cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \00A0";
}

body {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ced9e0;
}

a:hover {
  color: #006600;
}

header {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 4em;
  border-top: 2px solid #006600;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
  -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
  -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header {
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
}
header #logo-container {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 48.82117%;
}
header #logo-container:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header #logo-container {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header #logo-container:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
header #logo-container #logo {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  float: none;
}
header #logo-container #subtitle {
  color: #006600;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
header a {
  color: #006600;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
header a:hover {
  color: #d11c1c;
  border-color: #d11c1c;
}
header a:active, header a:focus {
  color: #d11c1c;
  border-color: #d11c1c;
}
header nav {
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 74.41059%;
}
header nav:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header nav {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 1em;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header nav:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
header nav ul {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  line-height: 60px;
}
header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header nav ul li {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
}
header nav ul li a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
header nav ul li a.bordered {
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 0.8em;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
  border: 2px solid #006600;
}

#content {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
  -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
  -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
  transition-delay: 350ms;
}
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#content section.intro {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
#content section.intro:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.intro {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
#content section.intro h1 {
  font-size: 8em;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.intro h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
  }
}
#content section.intro h1 span.nl {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.intro h1 span.nl {
    display: block;
  }
}
#content section.intro p {
  font-size: 2.0em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
#content section.row {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#content section.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#content section.row h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #006600;
  margin-bottom: 0.05em;
}
#content section.row p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
#content section.row .col, #content section.row .col-full {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 48.82117%;
  border-top: 2px solid #ced9e0;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#content section.row .col:last-child, #content section.row .col-full:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.row .col, #content section.row .col-full {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #content section.row .col:last-child, #content section.row .col-full:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
#content section.row .col-full {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 100%;
}
#content section.row .col-full:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.row .col-full {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #content section.row .col-full:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
#content .photo-grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-justify-content: space-between;
  -o-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
}
#content .photo-grid a {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#content .photo-grid a.col-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
#content .photo-grid a.col-2 {
  width: 49%;
  width: calc(50% - 12px);
}
#content .photo-grid a.col-3 {
  width: 32%;
  width: calc(33.33333% - 16px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content .photo-grid a {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #content .photo-grid a.col-2 {
    width: 49%;
    width: calc(50% - 7px);
  }
}

.loaded header {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
.loaded #content {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
Hello world I am 32 years old in 2015.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the following lines applied to `body` in your css:

```
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
  font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "frac", "pnum";
```

In particular the `"frac"` setting which enables automatic fractions:

> /* enable automatic fractions */
>   `.fractions { font-feature-settings: "frac"; }`

*font-feature-settings (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings)*

The following snippet demonstrates the intended usage for this setting:

```css
.fractions {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "frac";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "frac";
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "frac";
  font-feature-settings: "frac";
}
```

```html
<div class="fractions">Automatic fractions 1/2</div>
<div class="noFractions">No automatic fractions 1/2</div>
```

To fix make the following changes to your css:

- Remove the `"frac"` setting from each `font-feature-settings` declaration in the `body` selector

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

html, body {
  font-size: 100%;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

audio, canvas, video {
  display: inline-block;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
}

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

html, button, input, select, textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  outline: 0;
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b, strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

blockquote {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

pre, code, kbd, samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  _font-family: 'courier new', monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

small {
  font-size: 75%;
}

sub, sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

nav ul, nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

button, input {
  line-height: normal;
}

button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button[disabled], input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration, input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Neat 1.7.0
 * http://neat.bourbon.io
 * Copyright 2012-2014 thoughtbot, inc.
 * MIT License */
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum";
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum";
  font-feature-settings: "kern", "liga", "pnum";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-color: #22272a;
  color: #ced9e0;
  font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 0.75em;
  font-family: "font-family: " Helvetica Neue ",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
  color: #ced9e0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #9fb5c2;
  border-color: #9fb5c2;
}
a:active, a:focus {
  color: #9fb5c2;
  border-color: #9fb5c2;
  outline: none;
}

header {
  color: #fff;
}

hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

img,
picture {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

blockquote {
  border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
  color: #fdfdfe;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
}

cite {
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
}
cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \00A0";
}

body {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ced9e0;
}

a:hover {
  color: #006600;
}

header {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 4em;
  border-top: 2px solid #006600;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
  -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms;
  -moz-transition-delay: 50ms;
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header {
    margin-top: 2em;
  }
}
header #logo-container {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 48.82117%;
}
header #logo-container:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header #logo-container {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header #logo-container:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
header #logo-container #logo {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  float: none;
}
header #logo-container #subtitle {
  color: #006600;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
header a {
  color: #006600;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
header a:hover {
  color: #d11c1c;
  border-color: #d11c1c;
}
header a:active, header a:focus {
  color: #d11c1c;
  border-color: #d11c1c;
}
header nav {
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 74.41059%;
}
header nav:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header nav {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 1em;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header nav:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
header nav ul {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  line-height: 60px;
}
header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  header nav ul li {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
}
header nav ul li a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
header nav ul li a.bordered {
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 0.8em;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
  border: 2px solid #006600;
}

#content {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
  -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 350ms;
  -moz-transition-delay: 350ms;
  transition-delay: 350ms;
}
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#content section.intro {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
#content section.intro:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.intro {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}
#content section.intro h1 {
  font-size: 8em;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.intro h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
  }
}
#content section.intro h1 span.nl {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.intro h1 span.nl {
    display: block;
  }
}
#content section.intro p {
  font-size: 2.0em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
#content section.row {
  max-width: 68em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#content section.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#content section.row h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #006600;
  margin-bottom: 0.05em;
}
#content section.row p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
#content section.row .col, #content section.row .col-full {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 48.82117%;
  border-top: 2px solid #ced9e0;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#content section.row .col:last-child, #content section.row .col-full:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.row .col, #content section.row .col-full {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #content section.row .col:last-child, #content section.row .col-full:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
#content section.row .col-full {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 100%;
}
#content section.row .col-full:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content section.row .col-full {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 7.42297%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #content section.row .col-full:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
#content .photo-grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-justify-content: space-between;
  -o-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
}
#content .photo-grid a {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#content .photo-grid a.col-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
#content .photo-grid a.col-2 {
  width: 49%;
  width: calc(50% - 12px);
}
#content .photo-grid a.col-3 {
  width: 32%;
  width: calc(33.33333% - 16px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #content .photo-grid a {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #content .photo-grid a.col-2 {
    width: 49%;
    width: calc(50% - 7px);
  }
}

.loaded header {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
.loaded #content {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
Hello world I am 32 years old in 2015.
```