# Odd Behaviour with ContentEditable content

Tags: html, mysql, angular, contenteditable

I have an odd issue which for the life of me I cannot understand and hoping that someone has come across this before or may have a solution.

My Angular app is using a `contenteditable <div>` for the input of content which is working as expected with one exception. If the user types in a number followed by `a` or `o` the proceeding letter is superscripted for example:

1a shows as 1ª / 2o shows as 2º

I have tested this in Chrome / Safari / Firefox & Opera and it is consistent across all of them.

There is no additional characters or HTML stored in the database table either and when looking at the source the 1a is output as expected. This only happens with a number and with either `a` or `o` as the immediate next character all subsequent characters are as expected.

**Subsequent & Added Info**
The database that the content is being saved into is a MySQL db with a `UTF-8-MB4` encoding, would that be causing an issue here. However on looking at the data in the table its is stored as expected.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of the issue that you're having?

Comment: @IgorLima Unfortunately there is no code example that will help here I am using a standard $_POST method to send the data to a Laravel API endpoint which in turn sends the data to the MySQL database, The API is doing nothing other than storing the data. No HTML escapes or anything of that sort

Comment: Hm, searching a bit, it could be something along the lines of [Ligatures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures).  See if applying `font-variant-ligatures: none;` CSS rule on the `contenteditable` div does anything.

Comment: Also, [See this question about superscript characters in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350814/all-numbers-on-webpage-appear-in-superscript), maybe the answers there can help you out about this too.

Comment: @IgorLima thanks for the suggestion I have given this a try and no dice I am afraid

Comment: MySQL is not involved.  Provide hex dumps of the 2-char string at all stages of it being passed around.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a reproducible example, I'd suggest copying your html / css / javascript to stackblitz, and instead of making post calls just log the data.

Comment: Is this happening on different systems with different keyboards? Is the behaviour the same on mobiles or tablets?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you seem to have a CSS class or inline style with [ordinal numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric) turned on, adding the following css to your `contenteditable` styles should fix it:

```css
[contenteditable], [contenteditable] * {
    font-variant-numeric: normal!important;
}
```

Please check the following working example. The css `.ordinal` and `@font-face` is my guess about your issue. I've added the class `removed-ordinal` as an example of how to implement `font-variant-numeric: normal`.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  src: url("https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/font-features/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
.ordinal {
  font-variant-numeric: ordinal;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
}
.removed-ordinal /*,[contenteditable] *, [contenteditable] */ {
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-parent-which-inherits-ordinal-to-childrens ordinal">
    <div contenteditable>1a, 2o</div>
    <div contenteditable class="removed-ordinal">1a, 2o</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my example, when you write additional text to the first `div`, all the non-caps characters are written as ordinal text. The reason for that is that the font I'm using has been generated to do so. I recommend you to read about `OpenType`, [for ordinal numbers to work](https://reference.codeproject.com/css/font-variant-numeric#Values), specific glyphs should be used in the OpenType [`ordn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otvaroverview).

**More ways to fix your issue:**

1. Remove any `@font-face` you have in your css.
2. Change your `font-family` to one that doesn't have ordinals (ex. `font-family: serif;`)

Comment: This seems to make sense to me we use a font named Mulish from google fonts for the application I will need to check if it has ordinals

Comment: Regardless of it the font has ordinals or not, you can deactivate the _ordinal behaviour_, by setting `font-variant-numeric` to `normal`